# npx hardhat test returns "0 passing" no matter what I try

Tags: chai, ethers.js, hardhat

I am following this tutorial on youtube "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7QsqElEaWBQ"

And I have double checked to make sure my code matches, but I am stuck at the 41:00 minute mark where I am testing the project. It consistently shows "0 passing". There is no fail message which I saw in the tutorial video. This makes me believe that they aren't even getting tested. I have installed all dependencies required in the beginning, checked to make sure my file names match and still no luck. This test is using using hardhat-waffle.

Here is my "Testing.js" file code =>

```
    const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("ethers");
const {
  isCallTrace,
} = require("hardhat/internal/hardhat-network/stack-traces/message-trace");

describe("Staking", function () {
  beforeEach(async function () {
    [signer1, signers2] = await ethers.getSigners();

    Staking = await ethers.getContractFactory("Staking", signer1);

    staking = await Staking.deploy({
      value: ethers.utils.parseEther("10"),
    });
  });

  describe("deploy", function () {
    it("should set owner", async function () {
      expect(await staking.owner()).to.equal(signer1.address);
    });
    it("sets up tiers and lockPeriods", async function () {
      expect(await staking.lockPeriods(0)).to.equal(30);
      expect(await staking.lockPeriods(1)).to.equal(90);
      expect(await staking.lockPeriods(2)).to.equal(180);

      expect(await staking.tiers(3)).to.equal(700);
      expect(await staking.tiers(3)).to.equal(1000);
      expect(await staking.tiers(3)).to.equal(1200);
    });
  });

  describe("stakeEther", function () {
    it("transfers ether", async function () {
      const provider = waffle.provider;
      let contractBalance;
      let signerBalance;
      const transferAmount = ethers.utils.parseEther("2.0");

      contractBalance = await provider.getBalance(staking.address);
      signerBalance = await signer1.getBalance();

      const data = { value: transferAmount };
      const transaction = await staking.connect(signer1).stakeEther(30, data);
      const receipt = await transaction.wait();
      const gasUsed = receipt.gasUsed.mul(receipt.effectiveGasPrice);

      //test the change in signer1's ether balance
      expect(await signer1.getBalance()).to.equal(
        signerBalance.sub(transferAmount).sub(gasUsed)
      );

      // test the change in contract's ether balance
      expect(await provider.getBalance(staking.address)).to.equal(
        contractBalance.add(transferAmount)
      );
    });
  });
});
```

If you know how to solve my issue, please let me know. That would be a great help to me!

Comment: In which path did you create the folder called 'test'?

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure, that `Testing.js` is placed in the folder `test` and folder `test` is placed next to package.json

Answer (score 0):

Another problem that may bring rise to this scenario, is if   you had initialized git in your project and then created a new folder in this case `test` that will have an `untracked flag - U`. add the untracked files or folder by dong `git add .` and commit them `git commit -m "whatever message you want"` and then run the test command using `npm` or `yarn`. That was what worked for me. Hope it helps.
Cheers.